# quick question: how to associate a file with an ImageField in django?

Tags: python, django, filefield, imagefield

i have an image saved on my HDD and i want to assign it to an ImageField, but i don't know how.

i've tried something like this:
`object.imagefield.save(path,File(open(path)))`

But this makes an additional (invalid) copy of the image.

Can someone help me please?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually simply assign to the image field a string with the image's path, like this:

```
MyObject.image="/photo_path/photo_name.jpg"
MyObject.save()
```

I don't know if there is something wrong in doing that, but it always works.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but I do something like:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

srcFile = ContentFile( srcData ) # srcData is the contents of the local file
srcFile.open()
myObject.image.save(name=filename, content=srcFile)
```